# Manipulate numbers in string using php

Tags: php, string, replace, numbers, preg-replace

So I have this string:

100.25$-500$

I want to modify the numerical values then place it back into the string. So for instance I want to be able to take out each float value, manipulate it ex(100.25*10) and (500*2) and put it back in resulting in (1000.25$-1000$). It has to be flexible because the dollar sign can be on the other side as well.

Thanks in advance.

```
preg_match_all('/\d+/', $str, $matches);
echo $matches[0];
```

Comment: Since you haven't made an effort to solve the problem yourself, it seems that you're looking to [hire a freelancer to do your job for you](http://www.freelancer.com). StackOverflow is not and has not ever been a "give me teh codez" site. We help - we're not your free labour. If you - in fact - have made an effort yourself, you need to post your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can suggest this function

```
$correctionArr = array(10, 2);

echo changeString('100.25$-500$', $correctionArr);

function changeString($str, $correct){
    $array = explode('-', $str);
    if(count($array) > 0){
        foreach ($array as $key => $amount) {
            if(isset($correct[$key])){
                $return[] = (float)$amount * $correct[$key] . '$';
            }
            else $return[] = $amount;
        }

    }
    return implode('-', $return);
}
```

In correction array ($correctionArr) you you can set which amount you want to manipulate

Answer (score 0):

use regex (https://regex101.com/) for this (http://ideone.com/3JvnCZ)

```
<?php

$re = "/[\\d.]+/"; 
$str = "100.25$-500$"; 

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);

var_dump($matches);

echo ($matches[0][1] * 10) . "$-" . ($matches[0][1] * 2) . "$";
```

PS: do you have this values in a variable (post, get, json, etc.) before?